# How to remove reason and location from signature properties in Adobe

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have added a digital signature to a PDF with itext (v5.5.7) and Java. Created signature is verified correctly when I open PDF with Adobe Reader. However, when I see signature properties from signature panel of Adobe I can see two attributes (Reason and Location) with no value, because I don't want it, and I would like that these attributes don't appear in Adobe.

This is my implementation to add signature:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileToSign);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
if (hasSignature) {
    pdfStamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, bos, '\0', null, true);
} else {
    pdfStamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, bos, '\0');
}
pdfSigApp = pdfStamper.getSignatureAppearance();

pdfSigApp.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 15, 225, 15), 1, signatureFieldName);
pdfSigApp.setLayer2Text(signatureText);
pdfSigApp.setLayer2Font(new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA), 6));

PdfSignature sigDic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
sigDic.put(PdfName.FT, PdfName.SIG);
sigDic.setName(signatureText);

ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(sigDic);
MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(pdfSigApp, external, Integer.parseInt(SpringAccessPropertiesUtil
        .getProperty(PADES_INTERNAL_SIZE)));
```

I have tried to remove the attributes from the `pdfSignature`, but I don't achive any result:

```
sigDic.remove(PdfName.REASON);
sigDic.remove(PdfName.LOCATION);
```

I also try to remove the attributes in the method `modifySigningDictionary()` of my implementation of the `ExternalSignatureContainer`.

The attributes I would like to eliminate:

[image: I attach an image of the attributes I would like to eliminate.]

When I sign with a third-part application (applet) I obtain [a signature like I would like to get with itext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgQHN.jpg), so I expect it was possible.

[image: a signature like I would like to get with itext]

Comment: IMHO it might be possible that the properties panel might not care about what is present and what is not so there would be no way to "hide" the hidden stuff - but you might be lucky and someone else is able to show how...

Comment: Please share both PDFs so they can be inspected for differences.

Comment: You can download PDFs with this link                                          https://removewe.tl/LuOBaBr8JM removing the word 'remove' from the link